# How to add options to \Begin {Scope}

Tags: scoping

How to add options to \Begin {Scope} like [fill=..., shading angle, top color, bottom color]?

```
\begin {scope}[color=OrangeD]
\draw [-] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-5.25,1) (-5.15,1.15) (-4.8,1.3) (-4.6,1.6) (-4.3,1.7) (-4.05,2.05) (-3.75,2.1)};
\draw [-](-3.9,2.3) node (v2) {} -- +(0.55,-0.05) -- +(0.5,-0.65) -- +(0.35,-0.45) node (v1) {};
\draw [-] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(v1) (-3.8,1.8) (-4.05,1.45) (-4.35,1.35) (-4.5,1.05) (-4.9,0.9) (-5.05,0.65)};
\draw [-](-3.75,2.1)--(-3.9,2.3);
\end{scope}
```

Comment: \begin {scope}[color=OrangeD]


\draw [-] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-5.25,1) (-5.15,1.15) (-4.8,1.3) (-4.6,1.6) (-4.3,1.7) (-4.05,2.05) (-3.75,2.1)};

\draw [-](-3.9,2.3) node (v2) {} -- +(0.55,-0.05) -- +(0.5,-0.65) -- +(0.35,-0.45) node (v1) {};

\draw [-] plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(v1) (-3.8,1.8) (-4.05,1.45) (-4.35,1.35) (-4.5,1.05) (-4.9,0.9) (-5.05,0.65)};
\draw [-](-3.75,2.1)--(-3.9,2.3);
\end{scope}

Comment: The color is working but order "fill" is not.

Comment: instead of placing code in comments, please edit it into your question.  (that will, among other things, preserve linebreaks.)  also, a compilable example (which is desirable as it allows helpers to experiment rather than inventing something that may not be relevant) begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment as a comment. You could edit your question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

If you do `\begin{scope}[color=orange,fill=blue]`, that sets the default colors for drawing and filling. But it does not mean that all the paths will be drawn and filled. Take the example below, as no additional options are given to the path macros, `\draw` *just* draws the rectangle, `\fill` *just* fills it, while `\filldraw` does both. Note that I used `draw=orange`, not just `orange`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin {scope}[draw=orange,fill=blue,ultra thick]
\draw     (0,0)  rectangle ++(1,0.5) node [below right] {\texttt{\textbackslash draw}};
\fill     (0,-1) rectangle ++(1,0.5) node [below right] {\texttt{\textbackslash fill}};
\filldraw (0,-2) rectangle ++(1,0.5) node [below right] {\texttt{\textbackslash filldraw}};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can make all those three act the same, by doing

```
\begin {scope}[
  every path/.append style={draw=orange,fill=blue},
  ultra thick,xshift=3cm]
\draw     (0,0)  rectangle ++(1,0.5) node [below right] {\texttt{\textbackslash draw}};
\fill     (0,-1) rectangle ++(1,0.5) node [below right] {\texttt{\textbackslash fill}};
\filldraw (0,-2) rectangle ++(1,0.5) node [below right] {\texttt{\textbackslash filldraw}};
\end{scope}
```

Note the difference here, that the colour settings are added to the `every path` style, which means that inside the scope, `\draw (0,0) ...` will be akin to `\draw [draw=orange,fill=blue] (0,0) ...`, and similar for `\fill` and `\filldraw`:

[image: output with every path setting]

If you instead of `draw=orange` write just `orange`, or `color=orange`, that sets the default colour to orange, but it doesn't activate drawing for all paths, so with that setting you'll get

[image: output with orange instead of draw=orange]

All three rectangles are filled because of `fill=blue`, the second one doesn't have a border because it is a `\fill` without the `draw` option, and the node texts are orange, because setting a colour like this affects them as well.

For your arrow, I guess you want the outline one colour and the interior of the arrow a different colour. For that you should use a single path, not multiple ones, which makes a `scope` unnecessary, use

```
\filldraw [draw=orange,fill=blue]
 plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-5.25,1) (-5.15,1.15) (-4.8,1.3) (-4.6,1.6) (-4.3,1.7) (-4.05,2.05) (-3.75,2.1)}
 --(-3.9,2.3) node (v2) {} -- +(0.55,-0.05) -- +(0.5,-0.65) -- +(0.35,-0.45) node (v1) {}
-- plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(v1) (-3.8,1.8) (-4.05,1.45) (-4.35,1.35) (-4.5,1.05) (-4.9,0.9) (-5.05,0.65)};
```

which gives you

[image: blue wavy arrow with orange outline]